# How to setup Installer project with conditional file copying

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation, setup-project

I am building a VS 2010 installer, and I want to copy files to app folder depending on what options I select in UI (UI is not simple, so the only option is to show custom dialogs in Install custom action).
The problem is that custom action is actually executed after files are copied already.

One possible solution I can think of is to install all these files into the app dir, and then delete some unnesessary files in custom action. But these files are "secure" in some way, so I don't want to copy them to filesystem, even for a short period of time.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If your files shouldn't ever be on the filesystem, you have a problem in the requirements. The .msi storage itself is an open format and can be read by many tools, so if someone knows the file it's possible for them to find and extract it manually.

I agree that it's better to avoid deleting the files after they've been installed for two reasons. One: it avoids wasted work, and two: it won't cause repair scenarios due to missing files that Windows Installer thinks should be present. You should probably figure out how to determine whether these files should be present at an earlier stage of the installation, and set properties that cause this to happen (disable components by condition, or change feature states).

Answer (score 0):

Most controls in MSI dialogs use [installer properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372432%28VS.85%29.aspx). For example, a checkbox may use a property named MY_CHECKBOX which is set to a value or it's empty, based on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

These properties can be used to condition files:

- select your setup project in Solution Explorer
- click File System Editor button from Solution Explorer top pane
- select the file you want to condition
- in its Properties pane set [Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/025bcetc.aspx) field to the condition you want, for example

  MY_CHECKBOX = "value"